# Get product details by url key in Wordpress woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, customization

I want to load products deatails on my custom page.Is there any way that i can use the `url key` like `http://localhost/mysite/product/samsung-1`.In this url `samsung-1` is the key for that product.I want to use this and get product details like name,description and attributes.Can i do this using `url key` or i have to use id for this.thanks
I tried this code but this uses id :

```
<?php $post = get_post('5653'); //assuming $id has been initialized
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($post);
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply can use the existing function [`get_page_by_path()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path) for this, which has a third parameter `$post_type` you can specify. In your case a post from the custom post type `product` is what you want.

Basic example:

```
$product_obj = get_page_by_path( $slug, OBJECT, 'product' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your short answer.How to use the wc_get_product_terms() ?

Comment: [`wc_get_product_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy );`](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_product_terms.html) @MahmoodRehman

Comment: Attributes are saved as taxonomy, starting with the prefix »pa_«, so it could be »pa_whatever-called-it«. @MahmoodRehman

Answer (score 4):

You can use following function

```
/**
* Retrieve a product given its slug.
*/

function get_product_by_slug($page_slug, $output = OBJECT) {
    global $wpdb;
        $product = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type= %s", $page_slug, 'product'));
        if ( $product )
            return get_post($product, $output);

    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
$product = get_product_by_slug('samsung-1');
```

Its not tested though

Comment: Thanks great it working.but how can i get product attributes like i added camera->5px its not showing on details ?

Comment: Attributes need to be received additionally, e.g. with `wc_get_product_terms()`. @MahmoodRehman